# Change string if include strings from an array

Tags: php, jquery

I've created this jQuery method which checks if the input contains one of the strings in an array and if it does, removes it. How can I do that in PHP?

```
function changeName(name) {
    var team = name,
    removearray = ['.CS', ' Dota2', '-Dota2', ' Esports', 'eSports', ' Tactics', 'DotCom', ' DotA2', ' - LoL', '-LoL', ' Carry', ' LoL', ':)', '.de'];

    removearray.forEach(function( word ) {
        team = team.replace(word, "");
    });

    if (team == "Copenhagen") {
        team = "CPH Wolves";
    } else if (team == "Counter") {
        team = "CLG";
    } else if (team == "SamsungÂ Galaxy") {
        team = "Samsung Galaxy";
    } else if (team == "Meet Your") {
        team = "MYM";
    } else if (team == "Wheel Whreck While Whistling") {
        team = "Wheel";
    } 

    return team;
}
```

Comment: Where are you stuck, specifically?#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function changeName($name)
{
    $remove = ['.CS', ' Dota2', '-Dota2', ' Esports', 'eSports', ' Tactics', 'DotCom', ' DotA2', ' - LoL', '-LoL', ' Carry', ' LoL', ':)', '.de'];

    foreach ($remove as $r) {
        $name = str_replace($r, '', $name);
    }

    $replacements = array(
        'Copenhagen'                   => 'CPH Wolves',
        'Counter'                      => 'CLG',
        'SamsungÂ Galaxy'              => 'Samsung Galaxy',
        'Meet Your'                    => 'MYM',
        'Wheel Whreck While Whistling' => 'Wheel',
    );

    $name = isset($replacements[$name]) ? $replacements[$name] : $name;

    return $name;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$yourinputvalue = "whatever";    
$something = array (''.CS', ' Dota2', '-Dota2', ' Esports', 'eSports', ' Tactics', 'DotCom', ' DotA2', ' - LoL', '-LoL', ' Carry', ' LoL', ':)', '.de'');
    if (!in_array($yourinputvalue, $something))
    {
        //do whatever
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [array_search](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) function, for example:

```
$arr = ['str1', ..., 'strN'];
$keyToUnset = array_search('something', $arr);
if ($keyToUnset !== false ) {
    $arr[$keyToUnset] = ''; 
}
```